# bluebird promisify issue when browserified

Tags: node.js, browserify, bluebird

I am having an issue when working with browserified bluebird, the problem is with the promisify function.

**code:**

```
cat index.js 
var Promise = require ('bluebird');

function dosomething (cb) {
        cb(null,"I've done something");
} 

Promise.promisify(dosomething)()
        .then(function(result){
                console.log(result);
        })
```

**error:**

```
node bundle.js  
/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:3880
    return makeNodePromisified(callback, receiver, undefined,
           ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at promisify (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:3880:12)
    at Function.Promise.promisify (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:3894:15)
    at Object.bluebird (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:28:9)
    at s (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:1:316)
    at e (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:1:487)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/gulp-test/bundle.js:1:505)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

**gulpfile:**

```
cat gulpfile.js 
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return browserify('./index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

**Dependencies:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.3.4",
    "bluebird": "^3.3.5",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "notp": "^2.0.3",
    "thirty-two": "^1.0.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

If I create a promise manually it works fine:

```
var Promise = require ('bluebird');

function dosomething (cb) {
        cb(null,"I've done something");
} 


// manually promisified works fine
function Promisified () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        dosomething(function(error,result){
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(result);
        })
    })
}

Promisified()
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
```

I am using nodejs 0.12.04 but also the latest (4.4.3)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to run from the command line version optimized for the browser. If you run it in the browser - everything will be ok.

But why is this happening?

In this [line](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promisify.js#L244) bluebird decides what it is used when promisifyed - `makeNodePromisifiedEval` or `makeNodePromisifiedClosure`:

```
var makeNodePromisified = canEvaluate
    ? makeNodePromisifiedEval
    : makeNodePromisifiedClosure;
```

If you run from command line - `canEvaluate` is true, but due to [optimization](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/tools/build.js#L192) at building time for the browser version `makeNodePromisifiedEval` is [`undefined`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promisify.js#L91) because `__BROWSER__` will be replaced by `true`.

Comment: You have pointed me the right direction +1, however it didn't solve my problem.  I will accept your answer if you mention that there is `--node` option for browserify which wroked for me. didn't work straight away on gulp task because that option is not exposed, but I figured out  the right parameters: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1472#issuecomment-212823393

Comment: @Tiago The problem is that you're trying to run a script optimized for the browser on the server. And that will not work on the server: when `browserify` run he takes the prebuilded browser version of `bluebird` - https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/package.json#L70 and  https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-browser-resolve

Comment: I've got that, but browserify has an option to optimize for node too and that was what solved my problem (which I couldn't have done without your help. THANK YOU! ) . I don't plan to run my code in the browser but bundling it  with browserify makes it a  breeze to deploy specially on AWS lambda.  If you only change your answer to point to `--node` option of browserify I will accept it :)